# How to prevent event bubbling in React Native WebView?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

So, I've got Web application, mobile version of that is implemented using React Native WebView.
Issue appears only on mobile phone (testing on Iphone 14). On desktop version there is no issues.

About the issue:
In my app I've got a modal window with two buttons.
So, then I click on this modal window buttons, buttons under this modal are clicking...

Here is a short video of this bug: [Video](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/VhONDM0tzFz71g)

Buttons - MUI Components with onClick listeners:

```
                <Button
              className={actionButtonClassName}
              fullWidth
              color='secondary'
              variant='text'
              onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                e.stopPropagation()
                onReject()
              }}
              sx={{ fontSize: btnFontSize }}
            >
```

So I've tried also to set e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() to onTouchStart and onTouchEnd events, but all as the same...
I think, that onClick event is transforms to some another event in React Native WebView, but can't find solution in the internet.

I would be glad if anyone could help me to solve this issue. Thank you!